# MVC 2; How to copy a Html.EditorFor field in JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get used to the syntax in JQuery when using MVC 2.

I want to copy a phone number from 1 field to another. However the syntax of the line below is wrong;
`$("#contractAdministratorContact_Phone").val($("#contactClientContact_Phone").val());`

The above fields are defined as

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.clientContact.Phone)%>
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.contractAdministratorContact.Phone)%>
```

When I look at the page source, the Ids are contractAdministratorContact_Phone and contactClientContact_Phone

My script I locate at the bottom of my page;

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#chkCopyContact").click(function () {
            if ($("#chkCopyContact").is(":checked")) {
                alert("in!");
                $("#contractAdministratorContact_Phone").val($("#contactClientContact_Phone").val());
            }
            alert("done!");
        })
    });
</script>
```

So what should my JQuery set statement be instead?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that jQuery statement - it should set the value of the element with id `contractAdministratorContact_Phone` to the value of the element with id `contactClientContact_Phone`. Perhaps it is being executed at the wrong time? When do you want to copy the phone number? On a button click? When the other changes? etc.

Comment: I have updated my question to show the jquery function. The alert messageboxes get displayed. I have a click event on a checkbox.

Comment: I wish I could tell you what the problem is, but your code is good :) I took your JavaScript code, unaltered, and made a working example at http://jsfiddle.net/eNWbS/ - hope this helps out.

Comment: I am impressed with that tool. However when I used it, the values were NOT copied across.

Comment: I suggest you take it back to basics to try and find the root of your problem. Inside your `.is("checked") { }` put `alert($("#contactClientContact_Phone").val());` and `$("#contractAdministratorContact_Phone").val('New Value');`.

Do they work as expected?

Comment: @arame3333 I tested in Chrome, Firefox and IE and it worked in all three. What browser are you using? Also, I previously had an issue where one browser treated `click` differently than `change` for checkboxes - you might try using `change` instead of `click` for `chkCopyContact` - like so http://jsfiddle.net/WuuU4/

Comment: Well the event is firing as the alert messages appear. The alert($("#contactClientContact_Phone").val()); shows undefined

Comment: Ok. So strip it back some more to see if you can find the root of the problem. I would recommend using firebug to debug your javascript. My guess is that the id isn't correct... are you sure you have the correct id? For instance, `contractAdministratorContact.Phone` => `#contractAdministratorContact_Phone` so for `clientContact.Phone` should it be `#clientContact_Phone`?

Comment: Yes, you got it. I should have spotted that myself, but thanks to everyone, jsfiddle is a tool worth knowing about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$("#contractAdministratorContact_Phone").val($("#clientContact_Phone").val());
```

Notice that the first textbox id should be `clientContact_Phone` and not `contactClientContact_Phone` as in your example (Assuming the Html helper code is correct). Also make sure that the `:checked` condition evaluates to `true` so that this code is executed.